# Is it correct to say "Can you hear water babbling through the pipe"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I am sitting next to a waterspout along a building, then I hear some sound caused by water running through it.

**What is that sound called in English?**

According to my research,

> [to babble](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/babble_2): [intransitive] to make the sound of water flowing over
> rocks, like a stream

Can "**babble**" be applied to water running through a pipe?

Or Do we have another common term for it?

Is it correct to say "**Can you hear water babbling through the pipe**"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much more normally, we would refer to it *gurgling*.

> make a hollow bubbling sound like that made by water running out of a bottle:

I would not saying that "babbling" is wrong, but the connotation there is more of brooks and less of pipes.

Comment: Or of babies who can't talk yet, or people talking quickly and not clearly. The 'babbling brook' is a poetic metaphor.

Comment: @KateBunting when talking of water